# «Трижды раненному на войне» — верно написание с двумя НН?

Tags: нн

«Трижды раненному на войне» — верно написание с двумя НН?

Answer (score 2):

*Ране**н**ый* – правильный вариант написания отглагольного прилагательного.
Обозначает признак предмета. Слово образовано от глагола несовершенного вида "ранить", поэтому пишется с одной буквой "Н".
*Раненый солдат не оставил поле боя. Раненый боец уже две недели в госпитале.*

*Ране**нн**ый* – правильный вариант написания полного причастия (наш случай).
Обозначает признак предмета относительно действия. Согласно правилам две буквы "Н" в полных причастиях пишутся, если у причастия есть зависимые слова.

*Оливер Стоун – трижды оскароносный режиссёр, **дважды раненный на войне** во Вьетнаме.*

*Отцу-леснику, участнику первой мировой войны, **трижды раненному**, прошедшему весь ад окопной жизни, сын сообщал, что жив-здоров, что награжден двумя орденами.*

[Двойное Н и одно Н в суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени и соотносительных с ними прилагательных](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=5735)

Answer (score 1):

*Трижды **раненному** на войне...*

Показателем для написания двух НН является наличие зависимого слова ***трижды***.

В этом случае глагольная форма обозначает признак по действию и является причастием.

Answer (score 0):

Да. Его трижды ранили - чувствуете глагольность? Значит, не прилагательное, а причастие.