# Влияет ли наречие на определение части речи (прилагательное/причастие) и количество букв Н?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, наречия, части-речи, нн

Скажите, пожалуйста, может ли наречие являться зависимым словом и, соответственно, влиять на количество букв Н в прилагательных/причастиях?
Что-то я запутался, это ведь связь *примыкание* или нет? Например:

- *тяжело* ранен(н)ый солдат;
- гружён(н)ый *доверху* самосвал;
- жарен(н)ая *дочерна* картошка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопросов на эту тему было много, например:
["Раненый" или "раненный"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21595/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)
[«Трижды раненному на войне» — верно написание с двумя НН?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452032/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%9D%D0%9D)

И, конечно же, наречие является зависимым словом, связь — [примыкание](https://grammatika-rus.ru/svyaz-primykanie/).

*Раненый, гружёный, жареный* — отглагольные прилагательные (обозначают признак предмета).

*Ране**нн**ый тяжело, гружё**нн**ый доверху, жаре**нн**ый дочерна* — полные причастия с зависимыми словами (наречиями). Обозначают признак предмета относительно действия.

Подтверждающие примеры с наречиями есть в ПАС:
*контуженный в голову боец, **тяжело раненный** солдат* (как?), *раненный в ногу солдат, **только что крещённый** младенец* (когда?), но: *контуженый командир, раненый солдат, крещёный ребёнок.*

Там же есть примечание (привожу, так как вопрос связан с наречиями).

> Как видно из примеров, причастие опознается по наличию зависимых слов. Бывают, однако, редкие случаи, когда зависимое слово не является признаком причастия. Напр., следует писать: *у него усики явно крашеные* (ср. *явно искусственные*, где слово *явно* употреблено при прилагательном); *стены, раньше белёные, теперь покрыты зелёной краской* (ср. *стены, раньше белые*).

...и хотя потерь среди немцев не было, были **легко раненные** лопатами, искусанные и исцарапанные и один **тяжело раненный** ― ломом пробита голова, всё же Штальбе как честный офицер был вынужден указать в рапорте... [Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок (1975-1977)]

В эту скучнейшую пору в Карабас прибыл полковой грузовик, **груженный доверху** картошкой, но гнилой; пакостный ее дух так и ударял из кузова. [Олег Павлов. Казенная сказка (1993)]

Блюда кавказской кухни (шашлыки, мясо, **жаренное куском**) готовятся на шампурах или на вертеле. [Конкурс «От буржуйки до электроники» (2002) // «Биржа плюс свой дом» (Н. Новгород), 14.10.2002]

[Двойное н и одно н в суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени и соотносительных с ними прилагательных](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=5735)