# «Раненый в результате взрыва» — сколько «н»?

Tags: орфография, причастия, нн

*Умер раненый в результате взрыва в Бердянске замначальника ГАИ.*
В этом предложении в слове "раненый" должна быть одна "Н" или две?

Answer (score 3):

Эта тема не единожды рассматривалась на сайте.
Правильно писать так:
*Умер **раненный** в результате взрыва в Бердянске замначальника ГАИ.*
[Можно перестроить предложение:
Умер замначальника ГАИ, **раненный** в результате взрыва в Бердянске.]

В данном случае слово "раненный" является причастием, а конструкция "раненный в результате взрыва в Бердянске" — причастным оборотом (то есть причастием с зависимыми словами). В этом случае пишется ***-нн-***.
Из [правила](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62):
*в суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени пишется нн; как правило, эти причастия имеют приставки или пояснительные слова...*

Пытаясь спасти его, Румата роздал тридцать килограммов золота, потерял четырех агентов (благородных донов, не ведавших, что творят), едва не попался сам, ***раненный** во время попытки отбить осужденных*, но сделать ничего не смог. [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Трудно быть богом (1963)]

Теоретически возможно такое предложение:
***Раненый** умер в результате взрыва.*
Смысл: раненый (субстантивированное прилагательное, зависимых слов нет) находился в землянке (палатке, госпитале), но умер не от ранения, а от взрыва.

Дополнительную информацию, разъяснения и примеры можно посмотреть [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471761/%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81/471768#471768).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы написать правильно данное слово, вам необходимо четко понимать, в рамках какой темы рассматривается эта орфограмма.
Тема, которая рассматривается в рамках данного правила, звучит так: **"Правописание 'н и нн' в отглагольных прилагательных и причастиях".**

---

Это важно понимать, потому что есть похожая тема, в которой рассматриваются отыменные образования.
Соответственно, чтобы правильно написать, необходимо выяснить частеречную принадлежность данного слова:

- В полных формах причастий и причастиях, перешедших в прилагательные,
  пишется "нн"
- В полных формах отглагольных прилагательных  - "н". Не
  стоит забывать и об исключениях из правил.
  Есть четкий грамматический критерий для различения (это правило подходит для полных форм, ваш пример - это полная форма):
  1)Если слово образовано от глагола **совершенного** вида (это вопрос *"что сделать"* в начальной форме глагола)
  2)Если слово имеет в своем составе суффиксы "ова, ева, ирова"
  3)Если слово имеет другое зависимое слово
  В таком случае должно писаться "**нн**".

---

В вашем примере:
1)Слово **"раненный"** образовано от двувидового глагола "ранить", однако в этом случае можем утверждать, что "ранить" - это что сделать - здесь явно **совершенный вид**, что сделанный - ране**нн**ый.
2)Данное слово не имеет в своем составе суффиксов **"ова, ева, ирова"**
3)Слово **"раненный"** также имеет зависимое слово "в результате взрыва", раненный (когда) в результате взрыва. Это еще раз убеждает нас в том, что перед нами **причастие**, и поэтому надо писать "**нн**".